Extract vegetation estimation Google Earth image
I am trying to extract an estimate of the percentage of vegetation cover from a Google Earth image from 2011, I downloaded the image and using QGIS I put it in the band that has the most contrast between vegetation and sand (image below), how can I calculate the number of yellow, green and blue pixels that represent vegetation or some other element other than red.


You had a tag for Python but have not presented any code so I removed it.

One approach to this would be to reclassify the raster to a binary raster where every value greater than the "red" value is a 1 and every other value is a 0. You can use r.reclass in QGIS for that.
Essentially, you select your raster in the tool and provide a list of rules in a specific format for the reclass. The tool documentation contains some examples of how to write out different reclass rules. For your data, if all your vegetation values are <100 (as an example) and all your sand values are between 100 - 1000, your reclass rules could be:
0 thru 100 = 0
100 thru 1000 = 1
That would produce a raster where all the "vegetation" pixels are 0 and the "sand" pixels are 1. Once you get to that binary raster then there are some other tools you can use to count the number of 0 and 1 values, like the raster layer unique values report tool.
